# I'm trying to build a string from command line prompts in python, but I'm having trouble removing values from the list its in

Tags: python-3.x

I'm taking input from the command line as 100,1000 and converting it to a list and then adding up certain values to get what i want back to use as prameters elsewhere in the code.
But it does not remove the "0" value

```
        comParam1 = list((argv[1])) #how many steps they take
        cplist1 = comParam1[0] + comParam1[1] + comParam1[2]
        cplist2 = comParam1[4] + comParam1[5] +comParam1[6] +comParam1[7] 
        comParam1[0] = int(cplist1)
        comParam1[1] = int(cplist2)
        comParam1.remove("0")
        comParam1.remove(",")
        comParam1.remove("1")
        asdf = str(comParam1[:2])
```

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: a list of[100,1000]

Comment: It's removing the `0` entries here.  Do you have to reuse `comParam1`, or can you make a new list that doesn't have `0`'s in it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you want to achieve with you code but to make a list of numbers from the arguments I would do the following.

`doodle_argv.py`

```
import sys

input_list = []
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    try:
        input_list.append(float(arg))

    except ValueError:
        pass

print(input_list)
```

```
>>>python doodle_argv.py 10, a b 1000, 2000 , c 3000 4000
>>>[10.0, 1000.0, 2000.0, 3000.0, 4000.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

`remove(item)` only remove the first occurrence of `item` so you may need a while loop to keep removing until `"0"` not in list.

However, if you only need a list of integers from command line, you may try this:

```
from sys import argv
args = [int(i) for i in argv[1:]]
print(args)
print(args[0])
print(args[1])
```

Test run:

```
> python test.py 100,1000
[100, 1000]
100
1000
```

I'm using Windows Powershell, `,` is treated as a separator of arguments. `argv[1:]` gets all arguments except script names, list comprehension is used to turn all arguments to integer, you can access them by index for later use. Noted that no exception handling is present, so the code expects the input will be integer only.